# SonarQube Scan File/Directory Exclusions

Tags: sonarqube

In SQ, Folder/File exclusions can be set through the UI globally or at a project level (separate screens).  When scanning, if exclusions have been set in both places, are these then additive or does one set of exclusions take precedence over the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At project level you overwrite values from global configuration (treated as default).

In SonarQube 5.3 (currently I use this version) you can set at:

- global level:

  - `sonar.global.exclusions`
  - `sonar.global.test.exclusions`
  - `sonar.exclusions`
  - `sonar.test.exclusions`
- project level:

  - `sonar.exclusions`
  - `sonar.test.exclusions`

So if you set:

- `sonar.exclusions` and `sonar.test.exclusions` at both levels then runner will use values from project level
- all values at both levels, then runner will use:

  - `sonar.global.exclusions` and `sonar.global.test.exclusions` from global level
  - `sonar.exclusions` and `sonar.test.exclusions` from project level

  Runner will merge those values:

  - `sonar.global.exclusions` + `sonar.exclusions`
  - `sonar.global.test.exclusions` + `sonar.test.exclusions`

You can also overwrite project level configuration passing parameters to runner (see [analysis parameters](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters)).